# WHERE [Expression] = TRUE/FALSE in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a situation where I'm trying to filter people that have credits or not. Here's an example Dapper query for reference:

```
var sql = @"
    SELECT * 
    FROM Person 
    WHERE (Person.Credits > 0) = @hasCredits";

Connection.Query(sql, new { hasCredits });
```

I was pretty sure Postgres allows you to do this, hence my surprise when on SQL Server this failed with `Incorrect syntax near '='`.

With the sample data below, I would expect the query to return the Person with the ID of 1 when hasCredits is FALSE and the Person with the ID of 2 when hasCredits is TRUE.

```
INSERT INTO Person (PersonId, Credits) VALUES (1, 0), (2, 0);
```

**In SQL Server Is there a way to evaluate whether an expression evaluates to true or false?**

I've considered the following (horrible looking) options, but was hoping there was a more elegant solution:

- `"WHERE (Person.Credits " + (hasCredits ? ">" : "=") + " 0)"`
- `"WHERE (@hasCredits = 1 AND Person.Credits > 0) OR (@hasCredits = 0 AND Person.Credits = 0)"`

Comment: What is the use of `@hasCredits` here

Comment: It's a boolean to determine whether you want people with, or alternatively, without credits.

Comment: How will you identify people has credits or not. Its quite unclear can you add sample data and expected output

Comment: Oh sorry I though it was fairly clear. As an example it could be whether a "Person has credits" checkbox is checked when searching for people. Will add sample data.

Comment: In that case `(Person.Credits > 0)` condition would be sufficient to filter the people who has credits

Comment: OK, a radio button with "Has credits" | "Doesn't have credits" | "Don't care"

Answer (score 2):

Considering that when `Has credits` radio button is selected `@hasCredits` variable will have `1` else when `Doesn't have credits` is selected `@hasCredits` variable will have `0` else `@hasCredits` variable will be `null`

```
SELECT * 
FROM Person 
WHERE (Person.Credits > 0 and @hasCredits=1) or --Has credits
      (Person.Credits <1 and @hasCredits=0) or --Doesn't have credits
      (@hasCredits IS NULL) --Don't care
```

Comment: Consider adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to these types of queries. See this excellent article by Erland Sommarskog: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Comment: Is it really best to assume that the opposite of `>0` is `<1`? Why not stick with `<=0`?

Answer (score 1):

You question was quite plain and the answer is super easy!

```
case when Person.Credit > 0 then 1 else 0 end = @hasCredits
```

Comment: It should work, but it doesn't cover the case of `don't care`. Besides, most likely, any index on `Person.Credit` will not be used.

Comment: @vladimir OP doesn't indicate that null or "don't care" is an option. And concern about that case is a little contradictory to the concern about sargability. Do you see such a an index being chosen in another solution?

Comment: OP wrote about "Don't care" in the comments. If you use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` with the [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html), then optimizer would remove unneeded OR conditions. Maybe optimizer is smart enough in your case as well. Check execution plan of your variant and tell us.